# Using Button to Get A Value From onOptionsItem Selected

Tags: android, button, spinner

I'm making an app that can show Fruit Options on screen. The fruits are:

1. Apple
2. Grape
3. Orange

On screen process, i put switching process, so it will switch:

1. Apple first for 2 secs
2. Then switch to Grape for 2 secs
3. Then Switch Orange for 2 secs

The switching process will work continuously.

Now i want to make a "Choose Button" and a "Spinner" so the user can choose a fruit the will see his choice on "spinner".

For Example:
A user wants to choose an orange.

The user will wait till the "Orange" is shown on screen.

When "Orange" is being shown on the screen, directly he will press "Choose Button" then at the same time the "Spinner1" will be filled by "Orange Value".

*I don't want to use TextView.

Here is my code...

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
    private MenuItem Apple;
private MenuItem Grape;
private MenuItem Orange;

    private Spinner spinner;
    private Button choose_button;
    private Button btnPrice;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    choose_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        addListenerOnButton();
        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{ // i don't know what should i write here

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu");
    Apple = menu.add("Apple");
    Grape = menu.add("Grape");
    Orange = menu.add("Orange");

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem fruit) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Menu Item selected " + fruit);
    if (fruit == Apple) {
        frame.setViewMode(classfruit.apple);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                onOptionsItemSelected(Grape);}
                catch(Exception ex){}}
            }).start();
    } else if (fruit == Grape) {
        frame.setViewMode(classfruit.grape);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                onOptionsItemSelected(orange);}
                catch(Exception ex){}}
            }).start();
    } else if (fruit == orange) {
        frame.setViewMode(classfruit.orange);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                onOptionsItemSelected(apple);}
                catch(Exception ex){}}
            }).start();

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());

// get the selected dropdown list value
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

            btnPrice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrice);

btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
/* get fruit */
String fruit = String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem());

    /* get price */
String price = getPrice(fruit);

public String getPrice(String fruit) {
        String price = "0";
        if (fruit.equalsIgnoreCase("Apple")) {
            price = "1";
        } else if (warna.equalsIgnoreCase("Grape")) {
            price = "2";
        } else if (warna.equalsIgnoreCase("Orange")) {
            price = "3";
        }
```

**Main.XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:entries="@array/fruit"
/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/btn_choose" />
```

**String.xml**

```
<string name="btn_choose">Choose</string>

<string-array name="fruit">
    <item>Apple</item>
    <item>Grape</item>
    <item>Orange</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: So when user click on choose button then spinner item auto selected after 2 sec. stop ?

Comment: yes haresh, when user click on "choose button", directly the "choose button" will tell spinner what has been chosen.(example.orange) so the spinner will select automatically "orange".

Comment: You need fill the value in the spinner on the onclick of button

Comment: umm, sorry i still don't get it Wishy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my code:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.MyTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private Spinner spinner;
   private Button button;
   private Timer timer;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruit))));
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == (Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruit)).size()-1)){
                            spinner.setSelection(0);
                        }else{
                            spinner.setSelection(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        },0,2000);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
            String spinnerSelectedItem = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,spinnerSelectedItem,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry Haresh, it doesn't work.
for the first time i don't use adapter( because i don't know how to use it)
so directly i use android:entries @array/fruit.

can you help me just to get the fruit name (example.orange) using Click Button via onItemSelected. then "orange" will appear on spinner?

Comment: i forget to post my main xml so i've updated the code with Main.xml please help.

Comment: String selectedItemOfSpinner = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem(); just add this code on button click and u getting spinner current selected item in "selectedItemOfSpinner"

Comment: but it's work fine i also edited ans now you see button click listener and i also shown toast on button click.

Comment: thank you very much Haresh. i wish i can show you my problem by picture.

but, you give me an idea. I'll tell you when it works then > thanks :)

Comment: no, it wasn't me. you've been kind to me. i would never do that to you dude.

if i do that my reputation must be 125

Comment: Hi, Haresh, thank you very much it works, but it just didn't answer my question. How to make button recognize that the switching process is showing "orange"?

like i said before. you have given me an idea. so i try to use yours and i implement yours to recognize the "orange" (I add yours to my method "onOptionsItemSelected") while "orange" is being shown on screen. but still gives me nothing.

Comment: Hi, Haresh, finally it works... Thank you very much Haresh.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Haresh, my program is on the half way to work well.....

Next how to set this timers to be like this..

when app is started, **Only Spinner1 is running**( for now when app is started all spinners are running),

then when i click **btn_choose1** then the **Spinner1** is stop then **Spinner2** is starting till **btn_choose2** is clicked again then it is stop.

here is my code...

```
// get the selected dropdown list value
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

        btn_choose1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn_choose2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn_choose3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition() == (Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cincin_warna)).size()-1)){
                            spinner1.setSelection(0);
                        }else{
                            spinner1.setSelection(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        },0,1000);

        btn_choose1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(timer1!=null){
                    timer1.cancel();
                }
            }
        });

        timer2 = new Timer();
        timer2.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == (Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cincin_warna)).size()-1)){
                            spinner2.setSelection(0);
                        }else{
                            spinner2.setSelection(spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        },0,1000);

        btn_choose2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(timer2!=null){
                    timer2.cancel();
                }
            }
        });

        timer3 = new Timer();
        timer3.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition() == (Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cincin_warna)).size()-1)){
                            spinner3.setSelection(0);
                        }else{
                            spinner3.setSelection(spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        },0,1000);

        btn_choose3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(timer3!=null){
                    timer3.cancel();
                }
            }
        });
```