# How To Use Button To Choose On MenuOptions

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button, spinner

I'm making an app that can show City (Destination) Options on screen. The cities are:

1. Sydney
2. Melbourne
3. Darwin
4. Jakarta
5. Malaysia

On screen process, I put switching process so it will switch Sydney first then Melbourne then Darwin.The switching process will work continuously.

Now i want to make a "button" that will help user to choose the city. And the city will appear on a spinner

Ex:
A user wants to choose Melbourne.

The user will wait till the "Melbourne" text is appeared on screen.

When "Melbourne" is being shown on the screen, directly he will click "button" then "Melbourne" text will appear on a spinner

*I don't want to use Text View. just Spinner.

Here is my full code...

**MainActivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "Sample::Activity";

private MenuItem Sydney;
private MenuItem Melbourne;
private MenuItem Darwin;
private MenuItem Jakarta;
private MenuItem Malaysia;

private Spinner spinner1;
private Spinner spinner2;
private Spinner spinner3;
private Spinner spinner4;
private Button choose_button;
private Button price_button;

private ClassTwo classtwo;
FrameLayout frame;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(classtwo);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        choose_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        choose_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

        addListenerOnButton();
        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

        frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview);
        frame.addView(classtwo);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
   // What should i write in this method?
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu");
   Sydney = menu.add("Sydney");
    Melbourne = menu.add("Melbourne");
    Darwin = menu.add("Darwin");
    Jakarta = menu.add("Jakarta");
    Malaysia = menu.add("Malaysia");
            return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Menu Item selected " + item);
    if (item == Sydney) {
        classtwo.setViewMode(ClassTwo.Sydney);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                onOptionsItemSelected(Melbourne);}
                catch(Exception ex){}}
            }).start();
    } else if (item == Melbourne) {
        classtwo.setViewMode(ClassTwo.Melbourne);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                onOptionsItemSelected(Darwin);}
                catch(Exception ex){}}
            }).start();
    } else if (item == Darwin) {
        classtwo.setViewMode(ClassTwo.Darwin);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                onOptionsItemSelected(Jakarta);}
                catch(Exception ex){}}
            }).start();
    } else if (item == Jakarta) {
        classtwo.setViewMode(ClassTwo.Jakarta);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                onOptionsItemSelected(Malaysia);}
                catch(Exception ex){}}
            }).start();
    } else if (item == tombolMalaysia) {
        classtwo.setViewMode(ClassTwo.Malaysia);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                onOptionsItemSelected(Sydney);}
                catch(Exception ex){}}
            }).start();
    }
            return true;
    }

// SPINNER PROGRAM

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
    spinner4.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
}

// get the selected dropdown list value
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);

        price_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

        price_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /* get city */
                String city1 = String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem());
                String city2 = String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem());
                String multiply = String.valueOf(spinner3.getSelectedItem());
                String percentage = String.valueOf(spinner4.getSelectedItem());
                /* get price */
                String price1 = getCityPrice(city1);
                String price2 = getCityPrice(city2);
                int multiply = getMultiply(multiply);
                int percentage = getPercentage(percentage);

                String newPrice = price1.concat(price2);
                Integer price = Integer.parseInt(newPrice);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Result : " + "\n " + (price * multiply)

                        + " Ringgit +" + percentage + "%", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }

    public String getCityPrice(String city) {
        String Price = "0";
        if (warna.equalsIgnoreCase("Sydney")) {
            Price = "0";
        } else if (warna.equalsIgnoreCase("Melbourne")) {
            Price = "1";
        } else if (warna.equalsIgnoreCase("Darwin")) {
            Price = "2";
        } else if (warna.equalsIgnoreCase("Jakarta")) {
            Price = "3";
        } else if (warna.equalsIgnoreCase("Malaysia")) {
            Price = "4";
        } 
        return Price;
    }

    public int getMultiply(String city) {
        int Price = 1;
        if (city.equalsIgnoreCase("Sydney")) {
            Price = 1;
        } else if (city.equalsIgnoreCase("Melbourne")) {
            Price = 10;
        } else if (city.equalsIgnoreCase("Darwin")) {
            Price = 100;
        } else if (city.equalsIgnoreCase("Jakarta")) {
            Price = 1000;
        } else if (city.equalsIgnoreCase("Malaysia")) {
            Price = 10000;
        } 
        return Price;
    }

    public int getPercentage(String city) {
        int Price = 0;
        if (city.equalsIgnoreCase("Sydney")) {
            Price = 5;
        } else if (city.equalsIgnoreCase("Malaysia")) {
            return 5;

        }
        return Price;
    }
```

**Activity_Main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:entries="@array/city"
    />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:entries="@array/city"
    />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:entries="@array/city"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp" >
</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSumbit"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="86dp"
    android:text="@string/price_button" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:entries="@array/percentage"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSubmit"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="@string/choose_button" />
```

**STRING.XML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">CityDestination</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="tmbsubmit">price_button</string>
    <string name="button1">choose_button</string>

    <string-array name="city">
        <item>Sydney</item>
        <item>Melbourne</item>
        <item>Darwin</item>
        <item>Jakarta</item>
        <item>Malaysia</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="percentage">
        <item>Sydney</item>
        <item>Malaysia</item>

    </string-array>
    </resources>
```

My Question:

**How to connectify `choose_button` to spinners so when user click `choose_button` directly city selected will be appeared on spinner?**

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353466/using-button-to-get-a-value-from-onoptionsitem-selected/19353688#19353688

Comment: thanks Haresh. yeah that is absolutely like my case here.
you suggest him to use String selectedItemOfSpinner = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();

i've been suggested before same way with yours, but it says the local variabel selectedItemOfSpinner still not used.

Comment: oh man, it still doesn't work. *sigh

Answer (score 0):

In your `choose_button` when it is pressed you need to get the text of your spinner

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     **What should i write in this method?**
    Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    //call required function
    //e.g. String str = getCityPrice...
    //now set this text wherever you need to 
}
```

Comment: @user2877877 is that more helpful?

Comment: @user2877877 okay let me know if you get stuck

Comment: I'm sorry bro i'm still confused on "do something" what should i do.

Comment: @user2877877 what do you want to if the content of the spinner matches "Malaysia" for example? that is the code that goes in `//do something`

Comment: each spinners will have different behaviour

spinner1 = spinner2 (City's Name)

spinner3 = multiply

spinner4 = percentage

so if the content of the spinner1 matches "Malaysia" it will give price 4. 

oh man, i'm still confused about "switch(text)" and my method that i've done before "getCityPrice"? can you look at my method "getCityPrice" ?

Comment: @user2877877 okay so for each `button` you will have to get the `text` in the spinner. Just like we did above. Then instead of the switch call the respective method so in the `button` for the `price` call the function `getCityPrice()` with the text

Comment: *sigh* @ilovepjs : i still stuck in this  following code after "String text". 
do you mean each button when we click will have to get the text in the spinner? I think the reverse is my goal (The button that we click will be based on menuOptions and directly will tell spinner to search automatically the "chosen city"
* the spinner only serves the city names. so the button will confirm that "chosen city" from menuOptions

Comment: here is the flowchart program >>when user wants to choose (example).Melbourne, he will wait till the "Melbourne" is appeared on the screen. At the same time he will click "button OK" and the spinner will be filled by "Melbourne" right after that.

Comment: is that more helpful bro for understanding the flowchart program?

Answer (score 0):

**How to connectify `choose_button` to spinners so when user click `choose_button` directly city selected will be appeared on spinner?**

There is a method in Button `OnclickListener` you need to override this method and in that method call the object of the spinner that will open the spinner when you click on Button

and in your Button call the following method with the instance of your spinner
Edit: Dummy Button is as following

```
private void DummyButton()

{
    DummyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                 String selectedItemOfSpinner = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();  //Click handler of your spinner
                //post your code here
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    });
}
```

Comment: something like this?

String selectedItemOfSpinner = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();

or can you give me an example?

Comment: i've tried your code but the local variabel "selectedItemOfSpinner" still not used.